# Append value to a comma separated column of multiple rows MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Is there a simple way to skip the comma if column is empty?

I need to add value to a comma separated column of all rows that match the same task_id

```
============================
id | task_id | comma_sep_col
============================
 1 | 20      |2,3
============================
 2 | 18      |
============================
 3 | 18      |1,3
============================
 4 | 18      |2,3
============================
```

I am using the follow:

```
$user_id = '1';
$comma_user_id = ','.$user_id;

$sql = "UPDATE tableName set `comma_sep_col` = CONCAT(`comma_sep_col`,'$comma_user_id') WHERE find_in_set('$user_id',`comma_sep_col`) = 0 AND `task_id` = $task_id";
```

RESULT:

```
============================
id | task_id | comma_sep_col
============================
 1 | 20      |2,3
============================
 2 | 18      |,1
============================
 3 | 18      |1,3
============================
 4 | 18      |2,3,1
============================
```

EXPECT RESULT:

```
============================
id | task_id | comma_sep_col
============================
 1 | 20      |2,3
============================
 2 | 18      |1
============================
 3 | 18      |1,3
============================
 4 | 18      |2,3,1
============================
```

SOLVED:

```
$sql = "UPDATE tableName set `comma_sep_col` = IF(`comma_sep_col` = '','$user_id',CONCAT(`comma_sep_col`, ',', '$user_id')) WHERE find_in_set('$user_id',`comma_sep_col`) = 0 AND `task_id` = $task_id";
```

Comment: $comma_user_id = $user_id ? ','.$user_id :$user_id use simple ternary operator

Comment: I don't know how it works inside the mysql statement which it doesn't. Can you explain further?

Comment: are you using php @michael

Comment: Yes. And I updated $comma_user_id = ','.$user_id; to $comma_user_id = $user_id ? ','.$user_id :$user_id; with the mysql statement untouched and it didn't work. I am assuming that means $sql = "UPDATE tableName set `comma_sep_col` = CONCAT(`comma_sep_col`,'$user_id ? ','.$user_id :$user_id') WHERE find_in_set('$user_id',`comma_sep_col`) = 0 AND `task_id` = $task_id";

Comment: you should just override the $user_id variable before mysql query are you getting it !!!

Comment: That was exactly what I did (with my mysql query statement untouched)

Comment: what issue your are facing ??

Comment: same result. with comma on empty column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try This

```
$user_id = '1';
$comma_user_id = ',' . $user_id;

$sql = "UPDATE tableName
  SET `comma_sep_col` = IF(
    comma_user_id = '',
    $user_id,
    CONCAT(`comma_sep_col`, '$comma_user_id'))
  WHERE find_in_set('$user_id',`comma_sep_col`) = 0
    AND `task_id` = $task_id";
```

Comment: not need of doing it in mysql best way is manipulate it inside php only by using ternary operator check my comment in the question

Comment: $comma_user_id == ''
should it be `comma_sep_col` == '' ?
Either way, it doesn't seems to work.

Comment: @MichaelEugeneYuen yes

Comment: It should be comma_sep_col = ' '. And it working great. Thanks for giving me the direction.

Can you correct your answer so I can accept that?